# python script ends between 2 for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

i'm pretty new to python and would like to copy some files from one location to another one and store some information within them inside a mysql database. I have to run the script 2 times until it works. After the first attempt it stops right after the first for-loop. Executing it a second time finishes everything.

```
import re, shutil, glob, os, MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "xxx",db = "test")
x = db.cursor()

delete = """DELETE FROM import WHERE fehler = '1'""" 
x.execute(delete)    # clear the table

dest = 'local'    # paths
path = 'local/*.txt'    # paths
files = glob.glob(path)    # paths

for orig in glob.glob(r'/mnt/sap01x/OUT/INT/success/*.txt'):
    shutil.copy2(orig, dest)    # copy all files from one to another dir

for file in files:    # starting to scan the files
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    output = re.search(r'error', lines) # regexp to search for 'error'
    if output:
        query = """INSERT INTO import (Fehler,Filename) VALUES ("1","%s")"""
            x.execute(query, file)    # insert error to db
            db.commit()
            os.remove(file)    # remove file
    else:
            os.remove(file)    # remove file

db.close()
```

Can someone advise what I do wrong?

Comment: You list the files before you copy them. Therefore `files` is an empty list. Either move `files = glob.glob(path)` in between the two loop or, better, simply build a list of all the files you copy in the first loop and use that in the second (`files = []` before the first loop, `files.append(dest)`  in the first loop).

Comment: As a sidenote, you never close `f` in your second loop. It will break if you have too many files in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:    # starting to scan the files
    with open(file, 'r') as f
      lines = f.read()
      output = re.search(r'error', lines) # regexp to search for 'error'
      if output:
          query = """INSERT INTO import (Fehler,Filename) VALUES ("1","%s")"""
              x.execute(query, file)    # insert error to db
              db.commit()
    os.remove(file)    # remove file
```